# How to retrieve Enhanced list metadata using sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

We can handle the default related list  to the enhanced list using the Lightning app builder page but I want to make it dynamically using metadata so no need  to change manually every time in each  and  every sandboxes

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Related List Type is stated in the FlexiPage metadata file, so retrieving the right page is all you need.
You could use [`sf project retrieve start`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_retrieve_start_unified) command, i.e.:

```
sf project retrieve start --source-dir force-app/main/default/flexipages/YOUR_RECORD_PAGE.flexipage-meta.xml
```

A `componentInstanceProperties` element with name equals to "relatedListComponentOverride" and value equals to "ADVGRID" is the one you're looking for.
So searching for `<value>ADVGRID</value>` in the metadata file you'll find something like:

```xml
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>relatedListComponentOverride</name>
    <value>ADVGRID</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>rowsToDisplay</name>
    <value>10</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>showActionBar</name>
    <value>true</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
<componentName>force:relatedListSingleContainer</componentName>
```

Please note that the pair "relatedListComponentOverride" and "ADVGRID" could also be related to a Dynamic Related List, which `componentName` is "lst:dynamicRelatedList"

---

If you want to change the metadata from a Default one to an Enhanced one, once you found the right component instance in the metadata file, just change

```xml
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>relatedListComponentOverride</name>
    <value>NONE</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

to

```xml
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>relatedListComponentOverride</name>
    <value>ADVGRID</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

Comment: what do I need to do here I retrieve the flexi page then where can I change this default to an enhanced list

Comment: @RohitKumar why you want to change it after retrieving it? You could change it via Lightning App Builder only once, then retrieve the metadata file and deploy it to every org you want.

Comment: @RohitKumar I edited the answer adding how to change from default to enhanced.

Comment: Thanks, bro It's working as I want.